# why does'nt my js code reflect the right runtime value?

Tags: javascript

When I run this code `(under a  <script> code)`

```
window.msg = { a: 0}
var b = window.msg;

function g()
{
    console.log(b)
}
msg = {  a: 1};
g()
```

in the console - I get {a: 0} .

why is that ? I thought that `msg = {  a: 1};` will update the reference...

Comment: In very simple terms: Assigning a new value to a variable **never** ( really, never!) changes the value of another variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're are creating the object `{ a: 0 }`, and assigning a reference to that object to `msg` and `b`. Later, you're creating a new object `{ a: 1 }`, and assigning a reference to that object to `msg`, but `b` is still referencing the original object:

```
window.msg = { a: 0} // msg --> { a: 0 }, b --> undefined
var b = window.msg;  // msg --> { a: 0 }, b --> { a: 0 }

msg = { a: 1};       // msg --> { a: 1 }, b --> { a: 0 }
g()                  // prints b --> { a: 0 }
```

Comment: what if i remove the first line? the value of window.msg will be undefined. but should b see the change ?

Comment: @doomday1 then `b` would always be `undefined`. The point is that the variables `msg` and `b` are independent of each other. Assigning a value to one doesn't effect the other. However, if they both reference the *same* object, then when you manipulate that object through one variable (e.g. `msg.a=1`, as in *Doge*'s answer), you can see that change by looking at the other variable; i.e. although the variables *themselves* are independent, the object that the reference is the same.

Answer (score 5):

If you change your code to:

```
window.msg = { a: 0}
var b = window.msg;

function g()
{
    console.log(b)
}
msg.a = 1; // this line is changed
g()
```

You will get `{a:1}`.

You're reassigning `msg` so `b` just points to the old value of `msg`.

`b` does not reference `window.msg` but the `{a:0}` object.